# How can i get GA client id within jsp or java code

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to send google analytics client id to server side where we will be running google measurement protocol API.

We have our GA implemented via GTM.

As per google recommendation, i am not supposed to parse _ga cookie hence i tried going through the recommended way. if i paste the code below on the console, it works fine but give me error ga reference is not defined as soon as i include this code within my jsp.

```
trackers = ga.getAll();
 var i, len;
  for (i = 0, len = trackers.length; i < len; i += 1) {
   if (trackers[i].get('trackingId') === "UA-62222232-2") {
    console.log(trackers[i].get('clientId'));
   }
 }
```

Please let me know what is the correct way of getting ga client id? i am unable to do so via jsp and thinking if it would be better to parse cookie within java code.

TIA

Comment: Java or javascript?

Comment: Java. ultimately i need to get the client id and send it to server.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the above code in a jsp file it becomes simply Javascript in the browser, so that's what you need to debug.

But I actually recommend that you ignore Googles' warning and simply parse the cookie. Even if you retrieve the clientId via Javascript you'd need to pass it on to the server, having the cookie parsed by server-side code solves that problem.

If you really want a fool-proof solution you can create and maintain a clientId in your Java code and pass it into the GA tag (e.g. via a datalayer variable since you use GTM). Since then you control the format for the client id yourself you can be sure that there are no surprises.

Comment: Thanks. yes parsing cookie is my last resort but i did wanted to try the solution provided by GA. i think the reason might be since we are using GA via GTM due to async nature ga tracker might not be available when my javascript fires.

Comment: Are you doing this within GTM ? If you put this in a custom HTML tag you can execute it via tag sequencing depending on the GA tag.  Or you follow Simo Ahavas article to access the clientid within the custom task in the tracker: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/use-customtask-access-tracker-values-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Unfortunately, i need to pass this value to server side hence i either need to do this via javascript fired on jsp or within java code itself.

Comment: Hi everyone. any other suggestion besides parsing cookie?